# Getting following message when opening a pdf "Internet cannot download ......xyz from abc.com The file could not be written in the cache" in IE?

Tags: file, pdf, servlets, attachment, websphere-6.1

Our Application is build on Spring framework and it is hosted on WAS 6.1. It was designed for the Internet Explorer 6 (as the users using IE 6). It is opening a pdf file through AJAX communication through the controller. In the background it calls a mq to fetch the byte[]. It is written in the bufferedOutputStream of the response.

It is working fine in development and testing environment but in production environment it is not working fine always. It is opening sometimes, sometimes it is not. (For load balancing we have more than 1 servers.)

Sometimes the request query string is set in the filename and while trying to save the attachment it is giving the following error message in the pop up:

"Internet cannot download ......url from abc.com The file could not be written in the cache"

PFB the code:

```
    byte[] letterByteArr = null;
    letterByteArr = fetchFromMQ();
    bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
                response.reset();
                response.setContentType(application/pdf);
                response.setHeader(Content-disposition, attachment; filename=LP.pdf);
                int length = letterByteArr.length;
                response.setContentLength(length);                  
                bufferedOutputStream.write(letterByteArr, 0, length);
                bufferedOutputStream.flush();
```

The similar piece of code is running fine in another application which is running in different jvm.

Could anyone suggest the possible solutions for this problem if they faced during your code implementation? Where could be the possible problem in WAS, network, IE or Abode?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds much like http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812935. The problem is, IE6 won't download the PDF file when it is served over HTTPS instead of HTTP while the `Cache-Control` and/or `Pragma` headers are set to `no-cache`.

Add the following response headers:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
```

Comment: This application is working fine in 2 other environments which are over HTTPS. Moreover in the production environment it is happening intermittently. If the headers are set to `no-cache` wont be affect all the environments? How come the other environments are still working and in prod it is opening sometimes? Can it be  specific to WAS or network related issues? Plz advice.

Comment: This is a browser specific setting. Just set those headers. It doesn't harm at all. Further, you really don't need to whine with "Plz advice". Just leave it away and ask the question the smart way (as you did perfectly until I read "Plz advice").

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem and I added the reponse headers to solve this problem.
But I had to remove the `response.reset();` ; only after that the downloading problem is not occuring.

I don't know the reason behind this but it's working.

The issue only is that the data of the excel is different to the data in pdf fiel in my application.